# Excel formula for Laplace distribution

Tags: data, probability, forecasting, excel

I am trying to create a forecast model, projecting the number of passengers through an airport over a period of time (daily, weekly, and monthly).  I've already used Excel's FORECAST and POISSON formulas, but I cant find one specifically for a Laplace distribution and/or transform.  What formula, or formulas,  should I use?  Thank you.

Comment: This isn't directly quant finance, but Wikipedia has all the formula and description you need to build this in excel (if the function does not exist already): https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I didnt see any excel formulas in the wikipedia reference you provided.  The input could be a total passenger enplanements per day for like 21 days.  Could be longer periods of time and by weekly or monthly intervals.  In trying to forecast, as best as possible.  That would be the expected output.